# Using iPhone screen as a display monitor

Tags: iphone, display, jailbreak

Has anybody come across somebody using iPhone hardware (intact/as is, or hacked, taken apart, disassembled. either way) to use the iPhone screen as a display monitor?

Comment: Don't take it apart - so much more fragile and you can enclose the phone in a box / enclosure if you feel that aesthetic if preferred...

Comment: I am also looking for information on this. I believe the asker is not only interested in using the included iPhone and wants to drive a screen through other means as well. At least that's what I'm looking for. I want to use the mass produced (see cheap) and excellent quality screens in some of my personal projects. Also as a user of Duet on all of my running devices (iPhones 6, SE, iPad Pro 9.7, 12.9) it works fantastic but it does not address the askers question and is ultimately detracting others from researching the topic for some unneeded free advertising.

Answer (score 5):

An app called [Duet](https://appsto.re/us/qLNX3.i) can make your iPhone a display for your Mac.

Comment: Also works for iPad!

Comment: Also works with android... supposedly. It worked for me yesterday. I had some issues today.

Answer (score 4):

**SideCar** for iPad

> With Sidecar, you can use your iPad as a display that extends or mirrors your Mac desktop.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210380

**Duet**

> Ex-Apple Engineers turn your iPad into an extra display. Now for Mac &
> PC.

http://www.duetdisplay.com/us

**Air Display**

> "You have a bunch of different options to turn your iPad into a second
> display, but we’ve had the most consistent luck with Air Display."

https://avatron.com/applications/air-display/

**iDisplay**

> "iDisplay app turns your iPad, iPad mini or iPhone into secondary
> screen - too good to be true." - MobileCrunch

http://www.getidisplay.com

Answer (score 1):

I had quite good experiences with `yam` (yet another monitor).

As of the time of writing this is ipad and mac only. It's cheaper than duet.