# Turn old iphone into extra monitor

Tags: iphone, display, screen, pc, monitoring

I've just been wondering lately, would it be possible to turn my old iPhone into a temperature / small extra -monitor? I know there are apps like iDisplay, Spacedesk and Splashtop for connecting your phone to your pc. I've also seen Cai's [post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/209593/using-iphone-screen-as-a-display-monitor). But the feature I've been lacking (might have missed it) is to boot the phone with the computer (guess it would be possible by telling the phone, if it receives power, turn on/ turn on screen). If I have to disassemble the phone, I'm fine with that, I'm not using it anyway. Btw, it's for a windows pc.

I mean, if I put the phone inside the computer chassis to monitor temps (and just for fun) it would be pretty annoying to turn it on and link it all the time. I know this is probably a lost cause, but still. Have I missed the perfect program?

Comment: If you have a Mac, you can technically use Handoff to use supported applications between your Mac and iPhone. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209455

Comment: @Todd I should have specified that, it's for a windows pc.